# Is there any way to install MySQL 5.1 and PHP 5.3 on Centos 7

Tags: ubuntu, centos, rhel, mysql, php5

Is there any way to install MySQL 5.1 and PHP 5.3 on Centos 7. I researched a lot but could not find any link which gives step by step procedure.  Can someone please give me steps to be followed to install these .

Comment: If you are running not just one, but 2 unsupported packages with known vulnerabilities then why run them on centos7? Setup a centos 5 VM/container

Answer (score 0):

There are no RPMs of MySQL 5.1 for CentOS 7.
Your only chance is to take the "generic tar-ball", its installation is described in the manual.
At the top of my head, I see two potential points of trouble:

1) You may need to disable SElinux.

2) Some system library may have had an API change between the build platform of the binaries and CentOS 7.

I have no info on PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try using  IUS Community Project repositories:

```
yum -y update
yum -y install epel-release
wget https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
rpm -Uvh ius-release*.rpm
yum -y update
yum -y install php56u php56u-opcache php56u-xml php56u-mcrypt php56u-gd php56u-devel php56u-mysql php56u-intl php56u-mbstring php56u-bcmath
```

You can change php5X or 7x for versions you want.

Another way to run ANY PHP version over any linux distribution is compiling it from sources.  Its simple.   Look this manual that explain how to run any version of PHP:  https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WSJ0LMIJW5syLCekyYTZALe4X_t_RI9umKwpM_2sO7g/preview

Regards.